# SPSS - assign a value to a macro argument by manipulating another argument

Tags: macros, spss

I am trying to build a macro with 2 arguments: 
- one of them is being passed when calling the macro, 
- the 2nd one is a transformation of the first.
Basically, I am trying to do a string transformation on the 1st argument, and use the result to run some syntax.

```
    Define !MyMacro (arg1=!tokens (1), arg2=!DEFAULT(SomeValue) !tokens(1))
    /*what I am trying to achieve is to 
    replace all "-" in arg1 with "_", but the syntax does not work with macro arguments:
    compute !arg2 = replace(!arg1,"-","_").

    /*I need arg 2 to be available further down the syntax, as a variable name:
    fre !arg2.
    !Enddefine.
```

Any suggestions on to work around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"-" being a special character divides strings into separete tokens in the macro parser. For this reason you can not read a string that contains "-" as a macro argument using !TOKENS(1) (like you did in your example).
This can cause problems in other cases but here we can turn the bug into a feature: the following macro runs through the separate tokens in !ARG1 and replaces "-" with "_". If there is no "-", there will only be one token in !ARG1 and nothing will change.

```
Define !MyMacro (arg1=!cmdend)
!let !arg2=""
!do !i !in(!arg1)
!if (!i="-") !then !let !arg2=!concat(!arg2,"_") !else !let !arg2=!concat(!arg2,!i) !ifend
!doend.
title !quote( !arg2).
freq !arg2 .
!enddefine.

!MyMacro arg1=turn-into_.
```

The previous macro will only work with "-" and similar special characters, the following one can be used for any character (though I still set it up for "-"):

```
Define !MyMacro (arg1=!cmdend)
!let !arg2=""
!do !i = 1 !to !length(!arg1)
!if (!substr(!arg1,!i,1)="-") !then !let !arg2=!concat(!arg2,"_") !else !let !arg2=!concat(!arg2,!substr(!arg1,!i,1)) !ifend
!doend.
title !quote(!arg2).
freq !arg2 .
!enddefine.

!MyMacro arg1=turn-into_.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you review the [Macro Directives (DEFINE-!ENDDEFINE command)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define_macro_directives.htm) documentation, you'll find in the [String Manipulation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define_string_manipulation_functions.htm) section that it is `!SUBSTR` that you require to make such replacements.

Given there is not a "REPLACE" string manipulation function within DEFINE/!ENDDEFINE you will have to use the combination of various other functions and so for which you may also find this [link](http://www.spsstools.net/pt/macros/545/) useful, to carry out arithmetic.

*(I have stopped coding in SPSS MACRO language for this purpose, as it is very, very ugly and given the use of Python within SPSS, I now prefer to code in Python which this would be extremely trivial to do).*